# Is it possible to conduct meta-analysis for interaction between two continuous variables

Tags: regression, interaction, meta-analysis, blocking

all.
I have conducted four studies to examine an 2-way interaction predicting a continuous outcome variable from a continuous independent variables and a continuous moderator. So everything is continuous.. I wonder whether it is possible or if so how could I perform a meta-analysis for the interaction? Do I need to block the continuous variable?

Comment: If you just want to analyse the interaction then just do it, no need to categorise essentially continuous variables. If you want to analyse the two main effects and the interaction you will need to extract the variance-covariance matrix and do a multivariate m-a.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I wonder if you can be a little bit specific. From what I understand of m-a on interaction between continuous IV and binary predictor, I could obtain the effect size r at each level/condition of the categorical predictor. But how can I do the same thing  (i.e., getting coefficient, or effect size) when both IV and moderator are continuous?

Comment: Usually when people fit interactions between continuous variables they just fit the linear by linear interaction so they only have one coefficient. If your scientific hypothesis involves interaction between higher order terms everything become more complex.

Comment: I get what you are saying. But the problem for us is that meta-analytical average b of interaction term is not that meaningful. a interaction beta of say .10 can entail a multitude of possibility. For example, when moderator is high, there is an effect of .10, but when the moderator is low, there is not, b = 0. Or when moderator is high, there is no effect, b = 0. But when moderator is low, there is a negative effect of b = -.10. What we are looking for is something that quantify the direction of slope difference across studies..